# Understanding an easy recursive function which calculates sum of first n Numbers with Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write my first recursive function in Python to calculate the sum of first n Natural Numbers.

Here's what I tried doing:

```
def sum_first(n):
    if n > 0:
        sum = n + sum_first(n-1)
        return sum
```

When Called, It shows this error :

```
sum_first(5)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I am not able to understand how recursive functions work and why do I get this error.

**Question 1**

Let's say, I call `sum_first(3)`. What I beleive and what I understood as of now, thing go like this :

=>  `sum = 3 + sum_first(2)`.

=>  So, `sum_first(2)` will be called. Which means, `sum = 2 + sum_first(1)`.

=> So, `sum_first(1)` will be called. Which means, `sum = 1 + sum_first(0)`.

=> Now, my function will not be called as `n = 0`. Also, since I don't have any value for `sum_first(0)` , I get the above error. Right?

**Question 2**

Let's say, I add the condition for `n=0` which return 0. Now, It should be like this.

=> `sum = 1 + sum_first(0)`
=>  `sum = 1 + 0`

But in this case, I will get `sum = 3 + 2 + 1 + 0`.

This also means that my `sum` was remembering these values from the very beginning when `sum_first(2)` was called.

Please guide me if I am correct in assuming this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hint: what happens when n <= 0?

Comment: The problem is that your `sumfirst` returns None if the `if` clause is False .. just `return` a value for the False case (you don't need `else:` as a True case would return)

Comment: What about `n * (n+1) // 2`?  ;-)

Comment: When it calls  sum_first(0), it returns nothing and it tries to add this object of type NoneType to the previous sum ...

Comment: Thank You @MarkRansom I tried adding a else block and it worked.

Comment: Thank You @ti7 . I will try it.

Comment: Yes.. I got it much better now @Jean-ClaudeColette

Comment: But @MarkRansom. I still don't get one thing. Does `sum` keeps remembering and adding previous numbers to `n`  when `sum_first(n-1)` is called?

Comment: This is one thing which is disturbing me a lot. Please explain

Comment: I want to understand how this recursion works behind the scenes.

Comment: That is... what happens when `sum_first(n-1)` is called?

Comment: `sum` doesn't "remember" anything. Each time you call a function, it gets its own set of parameters and local variables - even if it's the same function being called while it hasn't finished yet (recursion). There are things Python does differently from other popular languages, but this is one that every language you're ever likely to use does the same way.

Comment: Every time you call the function `sum` is recalculated, because you have a line `sum =` which does that.

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel This helped me in understanding more

Comment: I have edited my question neatly. Need help friends

Comment: It would be better if you a) read existing questions and answers about recursion; b) if you're still confused, start over with a new question that clearly explains the difficulty, following the guidelines from [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Your function is missing a base case. A base case is the case at the very beginning. In your example, the base case is what should be returned at n=0. A solution would be

```py
def sum_first(n):
    if n > 0:
        sum = n + sum_first(n-1)
        return sum
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: What happens when n comes down to 0 after 1?

Comment: I still don't get one thing. Does `sum` keeps remembering and adding previous numbers to `n` when `sum_first(n-1)` is called?

Comment: That is... what happens when `sum_first(n-1)` is called?

Comment: @Baazigar sum_first(0) == 0

Comment: Also, sum_first(n-1) does remember, this is called the stack.

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Comment: Have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to return an integer even when the recursion bottoms out. Think about what you should return for the case where n>0 is false and add an else branch.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation. I have edited my question with clean working. Need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it a simple `if`:

```
def sum_first(n):
    if not n:
      return n
    return n+sum_first(n-1)
```

Every time a function call is encountered, an entry is created in the stack by allocating some memory for the execution of that function and the control passes onto executing that function.

Whenever a return statement is encountered while executing a function, the data of that recursive execution of the function will be popped from the computer's stack memory, and the control moves back to the place where the function was called.